# assigning options to one lightning-combobox inside iteration applies to all lightning-combobox

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to achieve this functionality.

I am displaying all the campaign members in LWC for that,

I have declared an iteration over a list of campaign members in LWC that has status and substatus so lightning-combobox is defined only one time in code but displays number of times on UI according to the number of campaign members (since it is in for:each loop)

changing status (lightning-combobox) of one record should change the "options" only in that corresponding record's substatus (lightning-combobox).

instead of that, it's applying to all record's substatus (lightning-combobox) because all have options={options}

**HTML** snippet

```html
<template for:each={recordsToDisplay} for:item="camp">

    <span class="tooltip">
            <!-- {camp.Id} -->
            <a href={url} target="_blank" data-record-id={camp.ContactId}
                    onclick={viewContact}>{camp.Name}
            </a>
            <span class="tooltiptext">
                    <div class="marginClass">Contact Name : {camp.Name}</div>
                    <div class="marginClass">Mobile : {camp.MobilePhone}</div>
                    <div class="marginClass">Email : {camp.Email} </div>
                    Created Date : {camp.CreatedDate}
            </span>
    </span>

    <lightning-combobox
        name={camp.ContactId}
        value={camp.Status}
        options={statusOptions}
        onchange={handleStatusChange}>
    </lightning-combobox>

    <lightning-combobox
        name="Substatus {camp.ContactId}"           
        value={value}
        onchange={handleChange}
        options={options}>
    </lightning-combobox>
    
    <lightning-button
        variant="success"
        label="Save"
        title="Save" data-record-id={camp.Id}
        onclick={SavehandleClick}
        class="slds-m-left_x-small">
    </lightning-button>
        
</template>
```

**JS** snippet

```js
handleStatusChange(event) {

    let campaignMemberRecordId = event.target.name;
    this.changedStatus = event.detail.value;
    this.getCampaignMemberStatusChanged();
    
}


getCampaignMemberStatusChanged() {
    console.log('getCampaignMemberStatusChanged method called');
    getDependentPicklist({ pickValue: this.changedStatus }) // HERE MY CLASS RETURNS LIST OF SUBSTATUS
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('in success',result);
            console.log(result);
            let subStatusValues = result;
            let dropDownList = [];
            for(var i = 0; i<subStatusValues[0].subStatusValues.length; i++){
                dropDownList.push({
                    label: subStatusValues[i],
                    value: subStatusValues[i]
                });
            }
            this.options = dropDownList;
            console.log('this.options',this.options.length);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('in catch part', error);
            this.error = error;
        });
}
```

Comment: Please add pertinent HTML and Javascript code to your question. It facilitates answering.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the correct options to each iteration. I wrote up a simple example.

```javascript
const options1 = [
  { label: 'Pending', value: 'pending' },
  { label: 'Active', value: 'active' }
];
const suboptions1 = [
  { label: 'Provisioning', value: 'provisioning' },
  { label: 'Pending Activation', value: 'pending-activation' }
];
const suboptions2 = [
  { label: 'In Service', value: 'in-service' },
  { label: 'Scheduled Maintenance', value: 'scheduled-maintenance' }
];

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  @track items = [
    { id: 1, statusOptions: options1, substatusOptions: suboptions1 },
    { id: 2, statusOptions: options1, substatusOptions: suboptions1 }
  ];
  handleChange(event) {
    const item = this.items.find((item)=>`${item.id}`===`${event.target.dataset.id}`);
    if(event.target.value === 'pending') {
      item.substatusOptions = suboptions1;
    } else {
      item.substatusOptions = suboptions2;
    }
  }
```

You'll need to adjust this to deal with each row, but the point is, that you need to include the valid options for each iteration.

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/AspA6YKAvdWYmZbGXfSS/src/app.js?p=stories).